# Manually flush data from table streams in Snowflake

Tags: etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using table stream for my ETL pipeline. I am just wondering is there any possibility of flushing the data from table stream manually without saving it anywhere in other table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snowflake will advance the stream when it sees the stream after FROM in a DML statement. It doesn't care how or if you use the rows, so you can do this:

```
insert into JUNK_TABLE select ANY_COLUMN from MY_STREAM where false;
```

If you run just this part of the insert, you can see that nothing will get inserted:

```
select ANY_COLUMN from MY_STREAM where false;
```

The `where` clause will evaluate to false for every row because that's what it's set to return. This means the `insert` statement won't insert a single row, but it will consume the stream.

Here's a mini script to test this:

```
-- Quick setup:
create or replace table MY_TABLE(COL1 varchar);
create or replace stream MY_STREAM on table MY_TABLE;

--Create a junk table so the syntax works:
create table JUNK_TABLE like MY_TABLE;

insert into MY_TABLE(COL1) values ('Row1'), ('Row2'), ('Row3');

select * from MY_STREAM; --The stream has three rows

insert into JUNK_TABLE select COL1 from MY_STREAM where false;  --Consume the stream

select * from MY_STREAM; -- The stream has no rows

select * from JUNK_TABLE; -- Neither does the junk table because "where false" on the insert
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. dont we need to insert all rows from table stream to another table to set it false???

Comment: No, you don't have to insert any rows at all. Snowflake just sees the stream name in the `from` clause of an insert (or any DML statement) and advances the stream. The `where false` part just saves time because it doesn't have to select a single row for this to work -- you could also change that to `where 1 = 0` -- it's just saying "don't actually select any rows from the stream to save time".

Comment: can you please explain the query which you showed above. Like for example my stream name is test_stream and it is watching a table "test_table" for dml changes. I dont want to save any data from the stream after test_table changes. I am just using table streams as a trigger for my task.

Comment: I'll update the answer to elaborate and explain the point about not saving any data from the stream.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered recreating the Stream with a `CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM ...` ?
If you had to do thatperiodically, you could also make it part of a stored procedure to run within a scheduled Task.

Comment: Yes, that's another option and cleaner if you don't need to use `at` or `before` (time travel) on the stream after replacing it.